# String to date conversion having exception in parsing

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, parseexception

Hi I need to convert string to date below is my code,

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date date = format.parse(string);
System.out.println("Date././."+date);
```

If i run my code am getting parse exception as like below,

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "January 2,2010"

Comment: Well yes - look at the format of your actual value, and look at the pattern you're specifying. They're nothing like each other. Please read the documentation for `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: actually am getting this input string is from another file in the above mentioned format and the output also i need to be in this format(MM/dd/yyyy) so only i mentioned like this

Comment: Right, but you're not using that code to *format* - you're using it to *parse*. So parse with the pattern matching the input data, then format with another pattern. Read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/05/05/common-mistakes-in-datetime-formatting-and-parsing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format needs to match the date you're trying to parse. E.g., for your usecase:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: You only need 4 MMMM's to match arbitrarily longer text.

Comment: @DanielWiddis yup, sticky finger syndrome. Thanks for noticing! (edited and fixed).